# Select all samples with a specified base at a particular position

Tags: r, bioinformatics, fasta, phylogeny, ape-phylo

I'm new to programming in R and trying to do a very specific task.

I have a fasta sequence of n samples, which I read in `ape`:

```
library(ape)

matrix <- read.dna(myfasta, format="fasta", as.character=TRUE)
```

This created a matrix, like so:

```
|    | V1 | V2 | V3 | V4 |...
|------------------------|
|Seq1|  a |  t |  g |  c |...
|Seq2|  a |  t |  g |  a |...
|Seq3|  a |  t |  c |  c |...
|Seq4|  t |  t |  g |  a |...
|... |
```

Where Seq(n) is the DNA sequence for each sample, and V(n) denotes nucleotide position.

How can I select the sequences that bear a certain nucleotide (e.g. "a"), at a certain position (e.g. "V1"), and then return the sequences as a concatenated string?

So for position V1, I'd want to have something like "Seq1, Seq2, Seq3" and for position V4, for the same base, I'd want to have "Seq2, Seq4"

I've tried `which()` and `filter(matrix, V1 == "a")` but I'm struggling.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to select the `V1 == 'a'` rows with boolean indexing, and then extract `rownames`:

```r
rownames(example[example[,"V1"] == "a", ]) # "No304" "No306"
```

You mentioned `filter`, which looks like `dplyr`.  It's a little more cumbersome to use tidyverse methods to manipulate data for which row names are important, as row names are dropped by default.

If you wanted to use `filter`, you'd have to first save the row names as an explicit column:

```r
library(dplyr)

as.data.frame(example) %>% 
  mutate(sequence = rownames(.), .before = everything()) %>% 
  filter(V1 == "a") %>% 
  select(sequence)

  sequence
1    No304
2    No306
```

Data (from [`ape` read.dna docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ape/versions/5.4-1/topics/read.dna))

```r
library(ape)

cat(">No305",
    "NTTCGAAAAACACACCCACTACTAAAANTTATCAGTCACT",
    ">No304",
    "ATTCGAAAAACACACCCACTACTAAAAATTATCAACCACT",
    ">No306",
    "ATTCGAAAAACACACCCACTACTAAAAATTATCAATCACT",
    file = "exdna.fas", sep = "\n")

example <- read.dna("exdna.fas", format = "fasta", as.character = TRUE)
colnames(example) <- paste0("V", 1:ncol(example))

example
      V1  V2  V3  V4 ...
No305 "n" "t" "t" "c"
No304 "a" "t" "t" "c"
No306 "a" "t" "t" "c"
```